# AJAX not working with XAMPP or is it just impossible

Tags: ajax

I'm still relatively new to AJAX and am trying to figure out why my simple test is not working. From what I read AJAX will not work under one domain, and other words pop up like cross-site and remote server. Anyways my problem is is that I'm not sure if my code is wrong or simply what I'm trying to do is impossible. I created a simple ajax request to submit data when I click on the button. Here is the code for the first script.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
      function load(thediv, thefile) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
        } 
        else {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }   
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          }     
        }
        xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" onclick="load('adiv', 'hello.php');">
    <div id="adiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the file **hello.php**

```
<?php
  echo 'aaa';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is just an http request done in the background. But yes, there are security restrictions that prevent you doing a normal ajax request to any arbitrary server.

What your code is missing is actually setting the URL that you're placing the request to. You've got `hello.php` as a parameter to your load() function, but you never actually **USE** it. So you're doing an AJAX request to... "nowhere".

Comment: So if I was to upload this to an actual web server to be viewed online, I would have to put my hello.php file in a different web server and then call it in order for AJAX to work?

Comment: Any requests to a server OTHER than the one you got the javascript code from is considered cross-domain.