# Simple AJAX example for PHP not working

Tags: php, ajax

This is my first question regarding PHP so please bear with me. I've been following tutorials from phpacademy.org.

I'm stuck on one tutorial where an intro to AJAX is given. I typed in the exact code as the tutor, still its not working on my end.

I searched alot for it but it didnt help one bit. Could anybody help me out here? Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementsById('adiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'AJAX.inc.php', true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="adiv"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="load();">
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the AJAX.inc.php file:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello AJAX';
?>
```

However another [example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) from w3school.com is working.

**Possible duplicate:**
[AJAX not working with XAMPP or is it just impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569805/ajax-not-working-with-xampp-or-is-it-just-impossible)

But this question isn't properly answered (or I dont understand it). Would someone please clarify it?

Comment: Hm, you're going to have to investigate a little more before you can figure out what's wrong.  If you're in a browser that has developer tools (like Chrome, or Firefox with Firebug) then you can look at the console to see if your PHP file is being reached on the server, and if so, what the response is.  Also, put in a statement to catch other state changes (like if the request responds with an error!)

Comment: Although not strictly necessary, when it comes to ajax, I tend to use a library like jQuery as it makes it a lot easier, especially if you have to support older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `document.getElementsById` method.

```
document.getElementsById('adiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById('adiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: No that was just a typo. I soon figured it out and edited the question. It still doesnt work.

Comment: @AdnanZahid Updated, is that still a typo?

Comment: Listen, I was wondering why eclipse didnt detect it as syntax error. How can I make it detect the error?

Comment: @AdnanZahid I don't know eclipse didnt detect it, are you using the javascript development toolkit for eclipse? The simplest way is to use the debug tool of the browser.

Comment: No I'm using the php development kit, however a dialog once asked me would I like to use javascript and I clicked yes. Is anything else needed?

Comment: @AdnanZahid It can't detect such error, because you could define the function your self. The error could be detected only when you run the code.

Comment: I have done Android development using Eclipse. It actually does check both the library functions and user-defined functions. Its not so good when it comes to php. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById('adiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'ajax_php.php', true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="adiv"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="load();">
</body>
</html>
```